# Can KEDIT respect per-file line endings?

Tags: editor, newline, line-endings, eol

By default, the KEDIT text editor (the Mansfield Software Group one) adds windows-style CRLF line endings on all files, including unix-style LF files. How can I configure KEDIT to respect the existing newline sequence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit your KEDIT profile in winprof.kex to include the following at the end

```
set reprofile on
LOCATE 0
if lower(filestatus.3()) == 'lf' then
    'SET EOLOUT lf'
ELSE
    'SET EOLOUT crlf'
```

Reprofile ensures it parses for each file, LOCATE 0 forces the file to be opened, and then it inspects the existing line endings and updates appropriately. This also defaults to windows style CRLF endings for new files.